# adding collection to hashmap using generics

Tags: java, generics

I am receiving a large number of arraylists of objects that extend my object.  I want to insert them into a hashmap for faster referencing.  I decided to create a method to avoid duplicate code since it happens so often, and just for fun I want to be extra fancy and use generics.  There are a few ways I know to do this, but none seem very clean or pretty; I'm wondering if I'm missing an easier solution.  So I want to do something like this...

```
private void addToMap(Collections<? extends myObject> collection, Map<String, ? extends myObject> map){

  for(MyObject myObject: collection){
    map.put(myObject.getName(), myObject);
  }
}
```

The contract of the method would require that the collection provided stores the same class as map does.  I'm fine if the method throws an exception were someone to break that contract and try passing in two a collection that stored a different implementation of myObject then the map stored.

The code above fails, because I can't put 'myObject' into a collection expecting "? extends MyObject" to encourage type safety. I'm fine just casting it, but they only way I know to figure out how to cast it involves a few steps of ugly reflection and seems convoluted.  I could also create some sort of inner class to have more powerful generics available to me (to force collection and map to store the same type) but it also feels like overkill.

So, is there a simple or pretty manner to creating this method in the most intuitive-to-the-reader manner possible?  I know I could toss out the generics entirely and just cast everything from object, I'm just trying to figure out a more elegant method.

Comment: Should `? extends myObject` instead be `? extends MyObject`?

Comment: @RichardJPLeGuen: Neither, it should be `? super MyObject`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want the following:

```
private <T extends MyObject> void addToMap(
        Collection<T> collection,
        Map<String, ? super T> map
) {
    for (T myObject : collection) {
        map.put(myObject.getName(), myObject);
    }
}
```

More info:

- [Generic Methods (Java Tutorials article)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html)
- [What is PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs)

Comment: If you wanted to make this solution even more flexible you could use `Collection<? extends T>`.

Comment: @Jeffrey I considered that but it wouldn't add any further flexibility for the caller, since it already decides `T`. Thanks for the edit btw.

Comment: @Jeffrey Any reason you deleted your answer? I was about to abandon mine and upvote it.

Comment: I was going to edit in an explanation about the difference between `? extends` and `? super`, but your links have it covered (I'm saving that PECS one for later :)). +1

Comment: ah, I didn't think it would let me get away with generics like that in a method (rather then class level).  I tried it already; but guess I got the syntax wrong somehow

Comment: @dsollen I actually just fixed a typo in my answer - see my edit.

Comment: I was missing <T extends MyObject>  though just so you know void should come after the <T extends MyObject>, in case youw ant to update it for anyone else who needs help.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I think that depends on.

***Generics*** is designed and suitable in some senarios, in which the client code and service code are contracted tightly for stong-type transfering and evaluating. so Generics just offers us ***Precompile-time Safety*** in this cases, **BUT** it is not absolutely safe and convenient when client code do a silly casting to a wrong type and input them to Genrics collection. As we know the colleciton will collapse in runtime , but it is ok in compile-time.

***Generics*** is **NOT** suitable in some cases, in which **we ourselves can guarantee** some objects which we add to generics collection are correct, even they cannot be unifed or casted to one superclass strong-type. in this case, we can ignore generics by using raw type collections or using some collection like `List<Object>`. it 's right way to go.  **I think you maybe be in this cases**.